# How to open a page after playing audio file in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

I am using Cordova to create an application which runs in both iOS and Android. In this application I created a button that, when clicked, will play an audio file.

How do I make it open a new html page immediately after the audio file has played?

Comment: Get some information about single page applications. You should only use one index.html for all your code. Therefore you need a library like jquery and than your able to switch between pages via "... href='#page2'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_media.md.html) plugin for playing audio files then you can,

**First:**
Get the audio file duration by `media.getDuration();`

**Second:**
By setting `media.getCurrentPosition(mediaSuccess, [mediaError]);` you can get the current position of your audio file, compare `getduration()` and `currentPosition()`, if both are same it means your file finished playing

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Media plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.media) you can detect the media status and can detect the stop status of the media file.

```
media = new Media(src, success, error_error, media_status);

function media_status(code) {
    switch (code) :
    case Media.MEDIA_STOPPED : //change the page
    break;
}
```

Here is a list of status that you can detect

```
Media.MEDIA_NONE = 0;
Media.MEDIA_STARTING = 1;
Media.MEDIA_RUNNING = 2;
Media.MEDIA_PAUSED = 3;
Media.MEDIA_STOPPED = 4;
```